# Render a SwiftUI view into an image with opacity

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I need to render a SwiftUI view into an image with opacity, so that empty space of the view would be transparent when I layer the image above some background.

I use this code for conversion:

```swift
func convertViewToData<V>(view: V, size: CGSize)  -> UIImage? where V: View {
    guard let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
        return nil
    }
    let imageVC = UIHostingController(rootView: view.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    imageVC.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    rootVC.view.insertSubview(imageVC.view, at: 0)
    let uiImage = imageVC.view.asImage(size: size)
    imageVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
    return uiImage
}
extension UIView {
    func asImage(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.opaque = false
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: format).image { context in
            layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
extension View{
    func convertToImage(size: CGSize) -> UIImage?{
        convertViewToData(view: self, size: size)
    }
}
```

And this code to test the resulting image:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var view: some View{
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            view
            Image(uiImage: view.convertToImage(size: .init(width: 200, height: 200))!)
        } 
        .background(LinearGradient(stops: [.init(color: .green, location: 0), .init(color: .red, location: 1)], startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
    }
}
```

This code produces two instances of the text: the one on the left is layered on the gradient background, and the one on the right is on the black background:

[image]

Clearly, the transparent parts are replaced by the black color in the image.

I figured out that the alpha information is discarded somewhere in the convertViewToData, but I was not able to find a way to preserve it.